# Django 2 -403 forbidden error : Not able to make a get request from views.py

Tags: python, django, post, get, django-views

I want to enable GET request from a function in views.py and read the data. My function is in views.py which is triggered upon POST request.

```
@csrf_exempt
def paysuccess(request):
    #process requests
    URL ="http://example/apiusername=111390&pwd=123&circlecode=2&format=json"
    #make get request
    request=urllib.request.Request(URL) 
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    #read response
```

Traceback shows issues in csrf.py file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rhtry/redirect/redirect/views.py", line 174, in paysuccess
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 470, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 580, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 508, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 442, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 588, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: You're making a call to external API (this `URL` is a 3rd party)? The Forbidden comes from that URL you're fetching, so this has nothing to do with csrf. The fact that you're making your view csrf_exempt doesn't have anything to do with the fact that the API you're calling is returning HTTP 403.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set the user-agent header to make the site think you are using a browser. The code would then be:

```
@csrf_exempt
def paysuccess(request):

    URL ="http://example/apiusername=111390&pwd=123&circlecode=2&format=json"

    request=urllib.request.Request(URL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: @MohitKumar what website are you trying to connect?

Comment: @MohitKumar nice!